# Morningstar data import wont give all dates prices requested

Tags: python, finance

After yahoo and google fall, i found a guy who suggested downloading data from morningstar, but it will only give me as much as 5 days prices. I´ve tried with different dates but there is no way to make it work.

Im using python 3.6.5 and PyCharm.

```
import datetime
import pandas_datareader.data as web

start = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10)
df = web.DataReader("AAPL", 'morningstar', start, end)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
df = df.drop("Symbol", axis=1)

print(df.head())
```

Im new to python and coding in general, so if there is anything I can be more specific about, just make me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop `.head()` in

```
print(df.head())
```

because that's meant to yield the first 5 rows.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html

Comment: @CosmeFulanito you should accept this as an answer if it resolved your issue